# Calculate the derivative of a power of $f$ in terms of $f$ and $f'$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

(a) State precisely the definition of: a function $f$ is differentiable at a ∈ R.

(b) Prove that, if $f$ is differentiable at a, then f is continuous at a. You may
assume that
$f '(a) = \lim {f(x) - f(a)}/(x - a)$ as $x$ approaches $a$

(c) Assume that a function f is differentiable at each $x\in\mathbb R$ and also $f(x) > 0$
for all $x \in\mathbb R$. Use the definition of the derivative and standard limit laws to
calculate the derivative of:
$$g(x) = (f(x))^{0.25}$$
in terms of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

I did part a and b. But stuck at part (c), can anyone guide me on part (c)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the chain rule, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{f(x)}=\frac{1}{4}f(x)^{\frac{1}{4}-1}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{4\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}} $$
Using the limit definition of the derivative of $g(x)$, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt[4]{f(x)}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)}}{h}
$$
$$
=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)}}{h}\left[\frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}\right]
$$
$$
=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)f(x)^3}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)f(x+h)^3}-f(x)}{h\left(\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}\right)} 
$$
$$
=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)f(x)^3}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)f(x+h)^3}}{h}}{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}} 
$$
$$
=\frac{\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)f(x)^3}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)f(x+h)^3}}{h}}{\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}} 
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)f(x)^3}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)f(x+h)^3}}{h}}{\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}} 
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)f(x)^3}-\sqrt[4]{f(x)f(x+h)^3}}{h}\left[\frac{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3f(x)}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3f(x+h)}}{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3f(x)}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3f(x+h)}}\right]}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)f(x)+\sqrt{f(x)^3f(x+h)}-\sqrt{f(x+h)^3f(x)}-f(x+h)f(x)}{h\left(\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3f(x)}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3f(x+h)}\right)}}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x)\sqrt{f(x)f(x+h)}-f(x+h)\sqrt{f(x+h)f(x)}}{h\left(\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3f(x)}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3f(x+h)}\right)}}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\left[\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{f(x+h)f(x)}}{\sqrt[4]{f(x+h)^3f(x)}+\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3f(x+h)}}\right]\left[\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right]}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}
$$
$$
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)-\frac{f(x)}{2f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\right]}{2\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{4\sqrt[4]{f(x)^3}}
$$

Comment: But this is not in terms of f(x) and f'(x)

Comment: I think is still not enough for the final answer...Because it needs to be in f(x) not f(x+h)...thats y im still confused

Answer (score 0):

Chain rule.

$g$ is the composition of $f$ and some other function.